# How can I save the urls of the opened webpages into https://www.google.com/bookmarks/?

Tags: google-chrome, google-bookmarks

I have opened a number of web pages in Google Chrome browser in my android phone. Is it possible to conveniently save the urls of the opened webpages in https://www.google.com/bookmarks/?

Chrome browser on Android does't have the feature for bookmarking all opened tabs, if I am correct, so I would like to see if https://www.google.com/bookmarks/ is a workaround.

Comment: We can only answer for the case of your laptop, mobile phones are off topic here. If you need a solution involving Android apps or browsers then [android.se].

Comment: The post was asking about chrome browser. why did you migrate it here?

Answer (score 1):

Right click a tab, then click, "Bookmark all tabs" this can also be done with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> on Windows.

This will open up a prompt asking you where to save the bookmarks, you can choose a folder or create a new one from this prompt.

Comment: Thanks.  I posted my question on superuser.com, explaining that I want to see if I can use  https://www.google.com/bookmarks/  as a workaround for chrome browser on Android not supporting bookmarking all opened tabs.  The horrifying Superuser's moderator  "Mokubai" first removed android from my post, and then migrated my question here, without considering the post content, and witout my agreement. So I just  updated my post here to clarify my question. See my update.

Comment: One common workaround is to open the history on Chrome (PC) > Tabs from other devices > Three Dots next to phone's name > Open All. Then do what I said above.

Comment: When there are many tabs opened in chrome in android, will have to reload every tab manually, so that they can appear in history.  Imagine 300+tabs opened currently...